# viewing files on local machine via tor browser

Tags: windows, firefox, browsers, website, development

How does Tor browser handle opening,
local files such as html pages & php
stored on my own computer.

would it a) just open it directly from my pc hard-drive. or

b) re-route it via several other third parties,
only curious to know because i just wanted to see how some stylesheets and pages i made
would be rendered in tor (pressumable exactly the same as firefox). then it made me think, how it would handle or go about serving them?

any ideas, just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to be based more on how your OS works but I will try to answer the question.

First, the easy one.  In Firefox or any other normal browser, you can go to file:/// to browse your local filesystem.  This function is not available in Tor Browser if you don't have access to the / directory.

The error is:

```
Access to the file was denied

The file at / is not readable.

    It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

With that said, if you know the specific path of a local file or directory where you do have access, you can open it with Tor Browser.  So from the address bar, if I type: file:///home/user/, it will open and browser that directory.

Likewise, if I manually run ./start-tor-browser /home/user/index.html it will open it also.